# RegExp - If condition Passed then split using character [&.\/]

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I need to split the text using different characters like `[.\/]+` only if the text starts with `https`.

Example Text: `https://www.google.com/test`

By using the **Regular Expression** `([.\/]+)` Pattern, the text is split into `https:, www, google, com, test`

I want to do this only if the text starts with `https`.

I tried this `(?(?=https.*)[^\/.]+)`, but it is splitting into only `https:`. I want to split into `https:, www, google, com, test`.

Comment: Maybe `(?:\G[.\/]+|^(?=https))([^.\/]+)`? See https://regex101.com/r/5i5ZIs/1, you need to be able to get Group 1 value though.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do as follows:

```
String[] parts = text.matches("^https.*") ? text.split("[./]+") : new String[]{text};
```

Instead of `matches("^https.*")`, you can opt for `startsWith("https")` as well.

Comment: I can use only regular expression pattern in Elastic and it is not possible to write code.

Comment: can you share what you have written till now ?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(https:)//(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)/(\\w+)$
```

- `^` means beginning of string
- `(https:)` means create a group from the literal `https:`
- `//` are literals
- `(\\w+)` means group one or more word characters
- `\\.` means a literal dot (or period or full stop)
- `/` is a literal
- `$` means end of string

Consider following code:

```java
public class RegExTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "https://www.google.com/test";
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(https:)//(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)\\.(\\w+)/(\\w+)$");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            int count = matcher.groupCount();
            System.out.printf("Groups found: %d%n", count);
            for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
                System.out.printf("Group %d: %s%n", i, matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Nothing found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Above code outputs the following:

```
Groups found: 5
Group 0: https://www.google.com/test
Group 1: https:
Group 2: www
Group 3: google
Group 4: com
Group 5: test
```

Also refer to this [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/9pbGSk/1) and documentation of class [java.util.regex.Pattern](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)